# Why the Kafka 0.9.0.x windows version do not have kafka-consumer-groups.bat?

Tags: apache-kafka

Having problem in getting list of Consumers currently running on kafka using java code. Some how came across various answers but then i also came across an answer to look into "**kafka-consumer-groups.sh**".

As i am using kafka Windows version i could not find ***.bat*** file for it.

Why the Kafka 0.9.0.x windows version do not have **kafka-consumer-groups.bat**, is it discarded intentionally or renamed?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to think kafka-dev forgets to create a corresponding .bat script. Anyway, you could create your own:

%~dp0kafka-run-class.bat kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand %*

Comment: FORGETTING is not an option here, must be some valid reason.